# How add a time and schedule in table HTML - PHP

Tags: php, datetime, scheduling

I have a `temporary table SQL` that contains the information of my customers.
The user can add/modify or delete a customer or her contact information.
I did a HTML table contains the name of the users that did an update of a customer. I used the function  PHP `get_current_user`

My function is the following:

```
 public function getCorrespondentByIdBis($id) {
        $statement = "SELECT * FROM `correspondants_bis` WHERE `id`='" . $id . "'";
        $result = $this->_db->query($statement);
        while ($data = $result->fetch()) {
            $correspondent = new CorrespondentBis($data['id'], $data['code_client'], $data['name'], $data['surname'], $data['phone'], $data['fax'], $data['email'], get_current_user(), 0);
        }
        return $correspondent;
    }
```

I want add a column in my HTML table that contain the time and the schedule when the user do any modification.

can I use  `getlastmod` ?

```
<?php
// outputs e.g. 'Last modified: March 04 1998 20:43:59.'
echo "Last modified: " . date ("F d Y H:i:s.", getlastmod());
?>
```

Someone please can suggest me a solution?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can instead I suggest you to keep two fields

> **Created At** - When the record was first inserted/created. **Updated At**-
>   When the record has been updated/edited.

By this we can track the activities of any table and for both the fields keept `DATETIME` as a data type.